# How to know the size of a very small file?

Tags: shell

suppose I have a very simple ASCII file that only contains

```
11111111
```

now, I want to use a command to find how many bytes it really has, not how many bytes the system allocated for it. I tried

```
ln -s
```

and

```
du
```

but they only output

```
4
```

I think that's how many blocks the system allocates for this file, how can I use a command to find the size of such a small file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `du -b` to see the size of the file in bytes.

```
$ du -b file
9       file
```

Answer (score 4):

`wc -c` will do:

```
$ echo "11111111" > file
$ wc -c file
9 file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stat` command to get information on a file. For instance, the size of file in bytes is:

```
$ echo "11111111" > file
$ stat -c %s file
9
```

Type `man stat` to see all of the other useful things it can tell you about a file.